# A basic doubt on showing some function is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I want to prove that the function $f(x)=x^2$ is uniformly continuous in the interval $[0,1]$. For that I am taking two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ in $[0,1]$ such that $x_n - y_n \to 0$, then I want to prove that $x_n^2 -y_n^2 \to 0$. But if I expand the left hand side then what is the guarantee that the sequence $x_n + y_n$ converges? Without that, how can I say that $x_n^2 -y_n^2 \to 0$

Comment: It is sufficient that $x_n + y_n$ remains bounded.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, we don't need $x_n+y_n$ to converge, as Daniel Fischer points out in the comments. It's enough for us to notice that $|x_n+y_n|\le 2$ for all $n,$ so that $$|x_n^2-y_n^2|=|x_n+y_n||x_n-y_n|\le2|x_n-y_n|.$$ From there, the task is straightforward.